# writing text to a text file so that the result is immediately displayed

Tags: python, file, operating-system

how can I write something to a text file using python but at the same time so that the result is displayed immediately (without leaving and entering the file in the next time)

code:

```
import os

os.system("file.txt")

file = open("file.txt","a")

file.write("text")
```

Comment: You can keep writing to the file until you close the file stream

Answer (score 0):

To flush output buffers into the file, causing the "written" data to be written into the file right now, use

```py
file.flush()
```

Do this sparingly, and only when you really need it. It costs resources. If you do that after every write, you should expect performance to suffer greatly.

Comment: ok, but i need that all time it will update and displayed if i cant do every time flush can i every time that im writing something to file to close and open the txt file? for example by taskkkill and how can i close by python txt file?

Comment: you _can_ flush every time but don't be surprised if that impacts performance. if you don't need performance, then you have no worries. closing and reopening the file is worse than flushing. -- you are hard to understand. please review [ask] and maybe use machine translation from your native language if your english isn't that practiced.

Answer (score -1):

You could write whatever you like and alse oread it back inside a block of a `with` statement.

```py
file = "F:/code/hello_world.py"

with open(file, 'w') as f:
    
    # write something
    s = 'some test'
    f.write()

    # do some more code
    print(s)
    
    # keep writing code.
    s = s + ' more things'
    f.write()

# the file is closed here
print('the file is closed')
```

This way you are always inside the file until the block is exited.